# how to hide lines made by ruler in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

In my microsoft word there are lines which is shown by rulers i want to hide it i have disabled the ruler but the lines are not going off please help me to remove that lines below is link to image

[image: link to image microsoft word]

Answer (score 0):

What version of word are you using?

Dependent on your version you need to go to: Word Options.

In 2007 onward this is by the big Office Button)

Click the big office button and at the bottom right click options/advanced options/word options (depending on version)

Click Advanced on the left

Scroll down until you see the 'show document content ' section.

If there is a tick in the 'show text boundaries' box. Un tick it.

Hopefully this solves your problem.  :)

Comment: i have microsoft ofice 2010  and i cant see any office button see in the above image

Comment: In office 10 go to:  File  then click options from the left panel, then go to advanced settings and follow the above.